# Play and Sencha integration for touch based mobile webapp

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, spray

I need to develop mobile webapp which should be compatible with any mobile / touch based device (iphone, android etc..).

I really like the Play features, it matches almost everything we need, We've planned to use Play with Scala.

I've following doubts, Can you please help me on these:

1. Can Play be integrated with Sencha framework ?, Because I need to use sencha as my View layer.
2. I've chose Play mainly to support great Vertical Scalability, Which web server should I prefer, Built-in JBoss Netty or any Akka based web server, Spray etc.. ?  I am little confuse here because all are new names for me :)

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1. PlayFramework is a server side solution which will work with **any** client-side framework. So yes.
2. For Better scalability, use the built-in server. You can also use a tomcat or any servlet container, but all functionalities are not supported yet. And Spray is a different solution, not compatible with Play.